# How to fix Windows 10 memory leak caused by FortiClient 6.4.6?

Tags: windows-10, fortigate, forticlient

Poolmon confirms it's the FortiClient Web Filter driver `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\fortiwf2.sys` allocations growing to more than 10 GB in the non-paged pool.

[image: Poolom screenshot]

Comment: Use the workaround described over at https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Fortinet-Forum/FortiOS-6-4-7-is-out/m-p/84852?m=198545

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading FortiClient from 6.4.6.1658 to 7.0.3.0193 fixed it!